# Flattening a tree with parents/children and return all nodes

Tags: python, recursion, tree

It's probably too late, but I can't sleep until it's solved:

I've got a tree with some parents, which have children, which have also children etc.

Now I need a function to get all nodes from the tree.

This is what currently works, but only with one level of depth:

```
def nodes_from_tree(tree, parent):
    r = []
    if len(tree.get_children(parent)) == 0:
        return parent
    for child in tree.get_children(parent):
        r.append(nodes_from_tree(tree, child))
    return r
```

Then I tried to pass `r` through, so it remembers the children, but I'm using the function more then once and `r` stores cumulatively all nodes, although I'm setting it to `r=[]`:

```
def nodes_from_tree(tree, parent, r=[]):
    r = []
    if len(tree.get_children(parent)) == 0:
        return parent
    for child in tree.get_children(parent):
        r.append(nodes_from_tree(tree, child, r))
    return r
```

**Edit**: This is the tree structure:

```
parent1    parent2    parent3
   |          |          |
   |          |          |
 child        |          |
              |          |
      +--------------+   |
      |       |      |   |
    child   child  child |
      |                  |
  +---+---+              |
child   child        +---+---+
                     |       |
                   child     |
                             |
                       +-----+-----+-----+
                       |     |     |     |
                     child child child child
```

Available methods:

```
tree.get_parents()       # returns the nodes of the very top level
tree.get_children(node)  # returns the children of parent or child
```

Comment: how is the tree formated i.e: `(value,[(value,[...]),(child2),..])`?

Comment: What is it returning, and what do you expect? (You might want to answer for a much smaller example than the one you pasted as ASCII art…)

Comment: My guess is that your problem is using `append` where you meant `extend`, so you end up returning a list-of-lists tree instead of a flat list.

Comment: Also, your logic for the parent is wrong. You probably want to do `r = [parent]` to start with, and then add onto the end of that. (And then you don't need the `if` statement at all—if there are no children, you won't add anything onto the end, and will just return `parent` as-is.)

Comment: @septi could you tell me if the output from my answer was what you wanted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is just that you're accumulating things incorrectly.

First, if you hit an intermediate node, each child should return a list, but you're `append`ing that list instead of `extend`ing it. So, instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` you're going to get something like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`—in other words, you're just transforming it into a list-of-list tree, not a flat list. Change this to `extend`.

Second, if you hit a leaf node, you're not returning a list at all, just `parent`. Change this to `return [parent]`.

Third, if you hit an intermediate node, you don't include `parent` anywhere, so you're only going to end up with the leaves. But you wanted all the nodes. So change the `r = []` to `r = [parent]`.

And with that last change, you don't need the `if` block at all. If there are no children, the loop will happen 0 times, and you'll end up returning `[parent]` as-is, exactly as you wanted to.

So:

```
def nodes_from_tree(tree, parent, r=[]):
    r = [parent]
    for child in tree.get_children(parent):
        r.extend(nodes_from_tree(tree, child, r))
    return r
```

---

Meanwhile, while this version will *work*, it's still confused. You're mixing up two different styles of recursion. Passing an accumulator down the chain and adding to on the way down is one way to do it; returning values up the chain and accumulating results on the way up is the other. You're doing half of each.

As it turns out, the way you're doing the upstream recursion is making the downstream recursion have no effect at all. While you do pass an `r` down to each child, you never modify it, or even use it; you just create a new `r` list and return that.

The easiest way to fix that is to just remove the accumulator argument:

```
def nodes_from_tree(tree, parent):
    r = [parent]
    for child in tree.get_children(parent):
        r.extend(nodes_from_tree(tree, child))
    return r
```

(It's worth noting that branching recursion can only be tail-call-optimized if you do it in downstream accumulator style instead of upstream gathering style. But that doesn't really matter in Python, because Python doesn't do tail call optimization. So, write whichever one makes more sense to you.)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you want to make a flat list containing all the values in a tree, in which case a tree represented by tuples the following would work:

```
def nodes_from_tree(tree,nodes=list()):
    if isinstance(tree,tuple):
        for child in tree:
            nodes_from_tree(child,nodes=nodes)
    else:
        nodes.append(tree)

mynodes = []
tree = (('Root',
        ('Parent',(
            ('Child1',),
            ('Child2',)
            )
        ),
        ('Parent2',(
            ('child1',(
                ('childchild1','childchild2')
            )),
            ('child2',),
            ('child3',)
        )),
        ('Parent3',(
            ('child1',),
            ('child2',(
                ('childchild1',),
                ('childchild2',),
                ('childchild3',),
                ('childchild4',)
            ))
        ))
    ))
nodes_from_tree(tree,nodes=mynodes)
print(mynodes)
```

Produces

```
['Root', 'Parent', 'Child1', 'Child2', 'Parent2', 'child1', 'childchild1', 'childchild2',
 'child2', 'child3', 'Parent3', 'child1', 'child2', 'childchild1', 'childchild2', 'childchild3', 'childchild4']
```

Comment: You probably want to get rid of the default value for `nodes` (since you never use it), or add a wrapper that returns a value to the caller, or both. But otherwise, this is a good illustration of how to do downward-accumulating recursion.

Comment: Also, the OP's tree structure obviously isn't the same as yours; nodes aren't either tuples or strings. Instead, the tree is some object with `get_parent` and `get_children(node)` methods. So, asking whether it's the right results for his tree may be a little confusing, and it may be hard for him to understand why the code works. It might be better to rewrite it to follow his API.

Comment: +1 since it's in principle correct and points out nicely what I was doing wrong, but I abarnert had the best solution concerning my API.